# What's the difference between PAGE_EXECUTE and PAGE_EXECUTE_READ?

Tags: windows, winapi, virtual-memory

Windows provides 2 different [memory protection constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366786(v=VS.85).aspx) (e.g. for [VirtualProtect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx)'s third param) that seem to behave similarly: `PAGE_EXECUTE` and `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`.

It would seem `PAGE_EXECUTE` should be execute-only rights (without read). However, execute rights without read doesn't make much sense, since the CPU needs to read the instructions from the memory before it can decode and execute them. In addition, I read [here](http://www.kernelmode.info/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=4195) that indeed `PAGE_EXECUTE` memory also allows reading from it.

So.. Why are there two different constants, what's the difference between them? Why should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: I suspect completeness/symmetry, kind of like how there is a unary + operator in C that doesn't do anything in particular.

Comment: You don't see write-only or write-execute (without read) options, so not sure about that.. But a nice idea :)

Comment: The page protection options are over-specified for any practical processor you'd run Windows on.  It was designed to be architecture-agnostic, also supporting a Harvard architecture with separate memory busses for data and code.  Intel and AMD processors used to have only a write-enable bit in the page descriptor.  The no-execute bit got added later.  No option to disable reading.   So in practice the distinction does not matter, just pick the one that describes what you are going to do.